# 8 Day MODIS Raster to Monthly Average in R

Tags: r, gis, r-raster

I am using the MODIS MOD16A2 Evapotranspiration data set which comes as a 500x500 meter grid of the 8 day sum of evapotranspiration.  The first file ends in _001 which means that it starts on January 1st and goes until the 8th.  The next file, _009, then covers the 8th to the 16th of January and on and on.

What I am having trouble with is going from 8 day intervals to monthly averages.  The only way I can get it to work is to find the average daily ET for the 8 day period, make a layer for everyday of the year, fill the start dates with the average daily ET, carry the last observation forward and split into months from there.  The problem with this is that my rasters are very large and I don't have the computational power or time to create a raster 365 layers deep just to combine it down to 12 layers.

```
library(raster)

layers <- paste("MODIS", seq(from = 001, to = 365, by = 8), sep = "_")

sampleraster <- brick(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, nl = length(layers))

sampleraster[] <- round(runif(ncell(sampleraster))*50)

names(sampleraster) <- layers
```

This code creates a sample raster similar to mine where the layer names contain the day of the year which the period starts.

Any help getting these 46 layers to combine to 12 monthly averages would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe https://gis.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask that? But did you check out the `stars` package?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this problem. The first is to find weights to assign to each layer for computing monthly averages.

**Part 1 -- Get weights**

This is not a spatial problem, and there might be a more elegant solution, but the below should do it. Note that you need to specify the year, to be able to deal with leap years. From your description I take it that the file sequences starts anew each year on the first of January.

```
year <- 2017
# number of days in that year (leap year or not?)
ndays <- ifelse(((year %% 100 != 0) & (year %%4 ==0)) | (year %% 400==0), 366 , 365)

# how many layers?
n <- ceiling(ndays/8) 
# day of year for each layer
nn <- rep(1:n, each=8)[1:ndays] 

# day of year for each month
m <- as.integer(format(as.Date(1:ndays, origin=paste0(year-1, "-12-31")), "%m"))

x <- cbind(layer=nn, month=m)
```

`x` describes for each day of the year, which layer to use, and which month it is. Now we can, for each month, determine how much of each layer is in that month (a number between 0 and 8 days).

```
weights <- table(x[,1], x[,2])
head(weights)  
 #   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
 #1 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0
 #2 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0
 #3 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0
 #4 7 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0
 #5 0 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0
 #6 0 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0
```

Each column is a month, each row a layer.

**Part 2 -- Apply weights**

Now we turn to the example raster data

```
library(raster)
layers <- paste("MODIS", seq(from = 001, to = 365, by = 8), sep = "_")
r <- brick(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, nl = length(layers))
values(r) <- round(runif(ncell(r))*50)
names(r) <- layers
```

And apply the weights to compute weighted means for each month.

```
s <- list()
for (i in 1:12) {
    w <- weights[,i]
    x <- r[[which(w > 0)]]
    ww <- w[w > 0] / 8
    s[[i]] <- weighted.mean(x, ww)
}

s <- stack(s)
names(s) <- month.abb
s

#class       : RasterStack 
#dimensions  : 10, 10, 100, 12  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#names       : Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec 
#min values  :   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0 
#max values  :  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50,  50
```